# css height issue chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, height

Hy
I have a problem with css in chrome.
I have a mini cart in the right column and when I add products the cart box is getting bigger and comes over the footer instead of pushing it down.
This issue I have only in chrome browser.

Right column is set on auto height. If I set height (2000px), I get footer to go down, but I don't need a set height.

Thx

```
  <div ID="right">
<!--cart-bar open-->
  <div id="cart-bar">
  <!-- For Ajax -->
     <div id="ajjax" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">
                          <div class="cart"><span>`<a href="">Cart (0 products)`</a></span>
        </div>
        <div id="minicart">
              <div  style="cursor:pointer;">


<span class="minicart-total"></span>
    </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
            </div>
                     <div class="minicart-bottom">
            </div>
            <!--minicart closed-->
            <div class="contact"><img src="" height="74" border="0"/>
            </div><br />
         <a href="#"></a>
         </div>
      <!--right closed-->
      <div class="clear">
      </div>

      </form></div></div>
      <!--column-right closed-->
   </div>
<!--wrapp-content closed-->
<!--footer open-->




    #column-right #right {float:right; height:auto;}
    #minicart{width:240px; background:url(../images/minicart-bg.png) repeat-y; padding:2px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#839606;}
    .minicart-bottom{width:244px; height:16px; background:url(../images/minicart-bottom.png) no-repeat;}
    .minicart-product{width:auto; padding-top:4px; padding-bottom:4px; background:#fafafa;  }
```

I don't know if this is all relevant.

Comment: For best results, please post the relevant snippets of HTML and CSS so that we can examine your code to help find the problem. Bonus points for creating a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: My spidey sense tells me that you should post your relevant code...

Comment: Add to fiddle Mr 1 Point

Comment: I added the coding part

Answer (score 3):

Try pushing the footer down by setting the height of a wrapper (containing everything except for the footer) too 100%, give the footer a top margin -height so if the footer has a height of 200px give it a top-margin of -200px, at the bottom of your container div add an empty div with an height of 200px this will always push your footer down.

Also I think the reason why your cart overlaps your footer is because of the floating problem, try adding "clear: both;" to your footer element.